# Selecting data variables results in loss of coordinate information in xarray

Tags: python, coordinates, python-xarray, qgis, satellite

I wish to [subset my xarray `Dataset` via a list of variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031973/how-to-select-specific-data-variables-from-xarray-dataset). However, when I do so, the resultant Dataset no longer has the coordinate reference information, as evidenced by adding the subset as a layer in QGIS.

How can I keep the coordinate reference information after subsetting the original `Dataset`?

```
import xarray as xr

DS = xr.open_dataset("my_data.nc")
bands = ['CMI_C01','CMI_C02','CMI_C03']

# Test does not have coordinate reference information :(
test = DS[bands]
```

It is apparent that the coordinate reference information is not stored in the `.coords` attribute, due to the following not working:

```
# Test still does not have coordinate reference info
test = test.assign_coords(dict(DS.coords))

# When put into QGIS, does not have the CRS
test.to_netcdf("test.nc")
```

---

### **Where is the CRS stored for xarray Datasets?**

---

For background, I am using [GOES imagery from the public AWS s3 bucket.](https://noaa-goes16.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#ABI-L2-MCMIPC/)

This is what the original Dataset looks like:

```py
Dimensions:                                 (y: 1500, x: 2500,
                                             number_of_time_bounds: 2,
                                             number_of_image_bounds: 2, band: 1)
Coordinates: (3/37)
* t                                       datetime64[ns] 2017-03-04T08:38:0...
* y                                       (y) float32 0.1265 ... 0.04259
* x                                       (x) float32 -0.07501 ... 0.06493.47
   

Attributes: (2/29)
    naming_authority:          gov.nesdis.noaa
    Conventions:               CF-1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

coordinates in xarray refer to the dimension labels, and have nothing to do with spatial coordinate reference system metadata.

You're looking for xarray Attributes. These can be accessed with `.attrs`, and you can carry over attributes from one dataset to another with:

```py
test.attrs.update(DS.attrs)
```

You can carry over attributes within variables in a similar way:

```py
test[varname].attrs.update(DS[varname].attrs)
```

As an example, after computing a simple operation which does not change the set of data variables or coordinates, you could do the following:

```py
# simple operation, which removes all attributes but does not change
# the dataset's structure
ds = orig_ds * 2

ds.attrs.update(orig_ds.attrs)
for c in ds.coords.keys():
    ds[c].attrs.update(ds_orig[c].attrs)
for v in ds.data_vars.keys():
    ds[v].attrs.update(ds_orig[v].attrs)
```

Note that xarray does not explicitly handle CRS information *ever*, and additionally does not preserve attributes in computations by default. You can change this behavior to keep attributes across computation steps by default with:

```py
xr.set_options(keep_attrs=True)
```

See the [FAQ section: What is your approach to metadata?](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/getting-started-guide/faq.html#what-is-your-approach-to-metadata) for more information. Also see the docs on [Data Structures](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/data-structures.html) for more detail on the various xarray objects.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I now see that xarray does not explicitly handle metadata, so selecting bands must also include ways to update the attributes of the selection. 

However, trying your `test.attrs.update(DS.attrs)` method still did not yield a raster file with the correct coordinate reference information

Comment: if the attributes are on a variable within the dataset, be sure to update those as well, e.g. `test[variable].attrs.update(source_ds[variable].attrs)`. this does work, so if you have a specific workflow that's not working feel free to update your question or ask another one - it could be something about the way you're doing it that neads a tweak. but I use this all the time to preserve attributes. you can also use the set_options method.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. Indeed, the QGIS-readable geographic information of this particular data product was stored as a variable known as `'goes_imager_projection'`, so including this variable in the `bands` list allowed QGIS to recognize the geographic information associated with this product.